# How to manage flex cards with different width and height? - Tailwind

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I'm building a new website (with React TypeScript an Tailwind) for my agency, and we have a list of articles (News) which looks like this:

[image: example]

As you can see, we have 3 different sizes of cards to display.

My API request returns "small" / "medium" / "large" in the object of the article to say which kind of card the specific article need.

My question is:

- how can I deal this ?
- How can I say to my browser to not render with the order of objects received, and to fill the page "properly" ?
- By properly, I mean not letting "holes" in the page.

Here is an try with grids :

```
<div className="col-span-2 bg-white flex items-center justify-center">
                <div className="relative w-5/12">
                    <img src="./assets/images_mock/GoogleMyBusiness.png" alt="" />
                    <span className="absolute top-2 left-2 rounded-md bg-purple-800 text-white text-xs p-1 uppercase">TEST</span>
                </div>
                <div className="w-7/12">
                    <h3 className="font-NexaBlack text-xl">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</h3>
                    <p className="text-gray-800 text-sm mt-2">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
                    <button className="rounded-full mt-4 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 text-gray-500">
                        <Link to={'#'}>read article</Link>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="col-span-4 bg-white flex items-center justify-center">
                <div className="relative w-1/2">
                    <img src={RectangleNews} alt="" />
                    <span className="absolute top-2 left-2 rounded-md bg-purple-800 text-white text-xs p-1 uppercase">TEST</span>
                </div>
                <div className="w-1/2">
                    <h3 className="font-NexaBlack text-xl">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</h3>
                    <p className="text-gray-800 text-sm mt-2">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
                    <button className="rounded-full mt-4 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 text-gray-500">
                        <Link to={'#'}>read article</Link>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="col-span-2 bg-white flex items-center justify-center">
                <div className="relative w-5/12">
                    <img src="./assets/images_mock/InterkabNews.png" alt="" />
                    <span className="absolute top-2 left-2 rounded-md bg-teal-500 text-white text-xs p-1 uppercase">Interkab</span>
                </div>
                <div className="w-7/12">
                    <h3 className="font-NexaBlack text-xl">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</h3>
                    <p className="text-gray-800 text-sm mt-2">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
                    <button className="rounded-full mt-4 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 text-gray-500">
                        <Link to={'#'}>read article</Link>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

but this code does not re-arrange the divs to fit the width of the screen.

I tried to be as clear as possible.

Hope someone have a solution.

Thank you mates !

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask], and consider updating your question with a [mre] of your work-in-progress code so that we can better assist you :)

Comment: Hi Joh! I think your are looking for a *masonry grid*. Though probably possible, Flexbox is not very well suited to create such a layout. Search [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=masonry+grid) for 'masonry grid' and you problaby won't know which one to chose, that many examples...

Comment: It gets even better: new W3C drafts added 'masonry' layout to CSS grid [Check MDN: Masonry Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Masonry_Layout)